# MySQL/PHP: connecting two individual search forms

Tags: php, mysql

My situation: 
I have **two** different forms. One common search form where users can search for products by their name/description, and another form that lets users search for products by their location (postcode and city).

This is the html for my search form:

```
<form name="searchform" method="post" action="index.php?go" class="searchform">            
               <input type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="Suchen..." class="field_search" id="tags"> 
               </form>
```

and this is the html for my location-search form:

```
<form class="location" method="post" action="index.php?go_location">
           <input type="image" src="img/location/location.png" width="30" height="30" id="location_image" title="Ortung aktivieren"/>
           <input type="text" size="18" placeholder="PLZ, Ort" name="location" id="location" title="Standort angeben"/>
           <input type="image" name="" value="" src="img/location/go.png" width="30" height="30" id="location_submit"/>
      </form>
```

and the corresponding php:

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
if(isset($_GET['go'])){
if(preg_match("/[A-Z | a-z]+/", $_POST['search'])){
$input=$_POST['search'];

$currently_searching = true;

//connect to db

$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name LIKE '%".$input."%' OR Description LIKE '%".$input."%'";

//echo results
}}}}

elseif(isset($_POST['location'])){
if(isset($_GET['go_location'])){
$input_location=$_POST['location'];

$currently_locationing = true;

$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE Postcode LIKE '%".$input_location."%' OR City LIKE '%".$input_location."%' OR Combined LIKE '%".$input_location."%' OR Combined2 LIKE '%".$input_location."%'";

//echo results
}}}
```

Now, **individually**, they work fine. 
What I would like to achieve is connecting these two forms in a way that lets users who are already searching for a certain string (via the common search form) use the location - search form to narrow the results down to those corresponding with the given postcode...

I hope this is clear. I thought something like: If a user uses the common search form, the

```
$currently_searching
```

variable becomes "true", so **if** this variable is true **and** the user is using the location - search form, then connect them... so I tried adding something like this to the php-statement:

```
elseif(isset($_POST['location']) && $currently_searching == true){
if(isset($_GET['go_location']) && $currently_searching == true){
if($currently_searching == true){
$input_location=$_POST['location'];

$currently_locationing = true;

//connect to db

$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE (Name LIKE '%".$input."%' OR Description LIKE '%".$input."%') AND (Postcode LIKE '%".$input_location."%' OR City LIKE '%".$input_location."%' OR Combined LIKE '%".$input_location."%' OR Combined2 LIKE '%".$input_location."%')";

//echo results
}}}}
```

It doesn't work though. I'd appreciate some help guys! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't just use 1 form instead of 2? You can combine the 2 forms into 1 form and when you submit it, it will submit the location and the search information.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to combine both forms without screwing up the html, since the two forms are in two different divs in two different sections of the page. How can I do this without the html being affected??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little trick. Add the id `locationForm` to your location form and `searchForm` to your search form, so it looks like this:

```
<form id="locationForm" class="location" method="post" action="index.php?go">
    <input type="image" src="img/location/location.png" width="30" height="30" id="location_image" title="Ortung aktivieren"/>
    <input type="text" size="18" placeholder="PLZ, Ort" name="location" id="location" title="Standort angeben"/>
    <input type="image" name="" value="" src="img/location/go.png" width="30" height="30" id="location_submit"/>
</form>

<form id="searchForm" name="searchform" method="post" action="index.php?go" class="searchform">            
    <input type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="Suchen..." class="field_search" id="tags"> 
</form>
```

Then add this javascript:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).on('submit', '#locationForm, #searchForm',function(e){

        var locationInput = $('#locationForm input[name="location"]').clone();
        locationInput.attr('type','hidden');

        var searchInput = $('#searchForm input[name="search"]').clone();
        searchInput.attr('type','hidden');

        $('#locationForm').prepend(searchInput);
        $('#searchForm').prepend(locationInput);
    });
</script>
```

The javascript will add the search field to the location form and visa versa before submitting. So whenever you submit one of the forms, you will always have both values.

**EDIT**

In your `corresponding.php` you could use something like this if there are two seperate queries needed.

```
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name LIKE '%".$input."%' OR Description LIKE '%".$input."%'";
    //Execute query
    //Fetch results
}

if(isset($_POST['location']))
{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE Postcode LIKE '%".$input_location."%' OR City LIKE '%".$input_location."%' OR Combined LIKE '%".$input_location."%' OR Combined2 LIKE '%".$input_location."%'";
    //Execute query
    //Fetch results 
}

//Combine results of search and location query

//echo results
```

Or if it's possible to execute one query you can use this:

```
if(isset($_POST['search']) && isset($_POST['location']))
{
    $sql="HERE YOUR QUERY WHERE YOU CAN USE $_POST['search'] AND $_POST['location']";
    //Execute query
    //Fetch results
}

//Combine results of search and location query

//echo results
```

Comment: thanks for your help! Unfortunately something is not working. The location-form does not return anything anymore... And the common search form works as usual. Maybe there is a problem in php? FYI, I did not add that last block of php code in my question

Comment: I'm sorry, that's because i changed the `action`. I updated my answer, you just need to change the `action` attribute of the location form back to `index.php?go`.

Comment: I'm really sorry, same result... I also tried changing the action to "go" in php... But tell me, the result should be that if a user types something into both search fields and hits submit on one of them, both queries would run at the same time?

Comment: Updated my answer. Else you can try to add `print_r` add to top of the page. Both, `$_POST['location']` and $_POST['search']` should exist.

Comment: So I'm going to ADD something like the php you posted, not replace it (as I still want them to work separately as well), right?

Comment: If you want the forms work separately you should use the first PHP example i posted. Then they can work separately and together. The only thing the javascript trick does is add the input field of the other form to the submitting form. So in your PHP you can do whatever you want with the search and location value. You can replace my first PHP example with your current example and make it complete by executing the query and fetch the results.